# What happened with System.ServiceModel in Windows Phone 8?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, windows-phone-8, windows-10-universal

I'm working on cross-platform application for all mobile and desktop platforms. It's all in C#. I'm working in `Visual Studio` using `Xamarin`. It's a client-server app, so I use WCF.

Inspired by [Miguel Castro: Extreme WCF](http://www.codemag.com/article/0809101) I divided my solution into `WinForms` client, `Proxy`, `Contracts`, `Services` and `Console` server host. But projects like *Proxy* or *Contracts* must be created as PCL (Portable Class Library) and here is my problem - I can't use **System.ServiceModel** in PCL with Windows 10 or Windows Phone. What's going on? Why?

What's the best walkaround?

EDIT:
I guess there is no problem with `Windows Universal 10`, only with `Windows Phone 8`. When I check Windows 10, it automatically check back to `Windows 8`. VS says: *The following will be automatically targeted because the support the same set of portable APIs: Windows 8*

EDIT2: To be even more clear, I'm struggling implementing **this (below)** in Portable Class Libiray with checked **Windows Phone 8**:

```
using System.ServiceModel;

namespace Contracts
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IMyService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        int GetSomething();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt185502.aspx) for references on which APIs are supported on the Universal Windows Platform.

You can **consume** WCF services from Windows Phone 8 (as detailed [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/893352/Using-WCF-Service-in-Windows-Phone)) but I am not able to find any documentation that supports hosting WCF services from Windows Phone 8.

Comment: Ok, I guess `Windows Universal 10` is not a problem. Only `Windows Phone 8`

Comment: Windows Phone 8 is part of the Universal Windows Platform

Comment: I check `Windows Phone 8` in my PCL properties. And I don't have `System.ServiceModel`. Does that mean, that I can't consume my services in Windows Phone 8 app ?

Comment: Thanks, but this is so weird:/ In Windows Phone I can add Service Reference (while adding VS will create copy of my contract), but I can't create or reference contract I made before, like Miguel Castro told us to do:/ And we're not even talking about different OS. We're talking about two Microsoft technologies. Using Xamarin I can reference System.ServiceModel in iOS app, but in Windows Phone.. I can't. Is this a joke?

Comment: @Tom that's because of the features available in the core .NET Framework up to Windows Phone 8.1. There's the possibility that the Xamarin you're using is in fact targeting the UWP .NET, which is newer and has far more features. To say this as clear as possible: __You cannot **HOST** WCF services from WP8.1__

Comment: Yes, But when you add service reference VS will automatically create copy of Contracts in my client (WP8.1). So I don't understand why I can't create Contracts in WP8.1 manually.

Comment: Anyway, so when I create `Windows Universal 10` I can target Windows Phone 10? So did I understand it right that you can host WCF from WP10 but can't from WP8.1 ?

Comment: @Tom why wouldn't you just use the classes generated by VS automatically? You should be able to replace them with your own code easily

Comment: @Tom Windows Phone 10 has the ServiceModel namespaces available as you can see in the link of my post. Whether or not you can actually host a WCF service out of it, I'd have to try to know. I'm not sure why you want to host a WCF service from a phone anyway

Comment: It's not about hosting. I don't want to do that. It's because of my architecture. I'd like to have single file with Contracts in separate PCL, like Miguel Castro said. I just want to have `[ServiceContract]` decorator and that's it. No hosting, just a reference to lib with service contract. But I guess I can't do that

Comment: @Tom As far as I've seen, no. Besides, marking a class with `[ServiceContract]` only makes sense for classes that are, well, **Service contracts**.

Comment: But now, I think there are not many Windows 8 phones left. Most people upgraded to WP10, so I think I will make app for WP10 only.

Comment: @Tom on the contrary, I'd say that at least 70% of the phones are still WP8.1. This will change soon, however, as carrier releases the updates. Next 6 months most likely 90% or more will be WP10